# How can I apply a condition to multiple rows using SQL? CASE WHEN / PARTITION OVER

Tags: mysql, sql, case, window-functions, coalesce

I am trying to create a column that shows Yes or No based on a set of conditions. If the conditions are met, then 'Yes' would apply to every row in the group (even if the conditions are only met by some of the rows in the group).

This is what I have so far but it's yielding an error. In essence, if any of the rows belonging to the same shipment id has shipment name = 'CAL', I want the result to be 'Yes'.

```
CASE WHEN shipment.name = 'CAL' THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' OVER (PARTITION BY shipment.id) END AS fulfil
```

You can see my ideal table below

| shipment.id | shipment.name | fulfil |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | CAL | Yes |
| 1 | NEV | Yes |
| 2 | PEN | No |
| 2 | NEV | No |

Comment: you can't combine them that way window function have a fixed format, and no i can't see the wanted result as i don't know where it is coming from

Comment: What about a simple sub select like `CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM shipment s1 WHERE s1.id = shipment.id AND s1.name = 'CAL') THEN 'YES' ELSE 'NO' END as fulfil`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `MAX()` window function to return `'Yes'` when there is a name with 'CAL'.
If there isn't, `MAX()` will return `NULL` which will be turned to `'No'` by `COALESCE()`:

```
SELECT id, name,
       COALESCE(MAX(CASE WHEN name = 'CAL' THEN 'Yes' END) OVER (PARTITION BY id), 'No') AS fulfil
FROM shipment;
```